# Group theory and direct product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $x^2=e$ for any $x \in G$ (that is: every element other than identity is of order $2$). Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\ldots\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $x^2=e$ implies that $G$ is abelian since $(ab)^2=e$ so $abab=e$ hence $ba=a^{-1}b^{-1}=ab$ (because $a,b$ of order 2). Moreover you have that 2 divides the order of $G$. The result follows from Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: by Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, G is isomorphic to Z(m1)xZ(m2)....xZ(mn)xZ x Z...xZ....where m1 divides m2, m2 divides m3...then how this theorem apply the above result i m confused,,plz clear it a little bit more

Comment: @Yasir The $m_i$'s are all equal to 2 since all elements except $e$ have order 2.

Comment: okay but what about ZxZx...XZ...

Comment: but what about ZxZ...XZ?

Comment: @Yasir Recall that $G$ is a finite group and all its elements except $e$ have order 2.